# I can't seem to find a way to fetch a specific record from Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

This is a simple service I've built for Firebase for an application. I've had to jury-rig some elements and I've made absolutely sure I am using *the latest* versions of firebase and angular fire since it seems to be changing pretty fast.  These first few lines are pretty straightforward,

```
app.factory('Ship', function ($routeParams, $firebase, FIREBASE_URL) {

    var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'ships');
```

The problems begin here. Depending on what I intend to do with the firebase object, at times it needs to be $asObject, at other times not. It depends on the tutorial and the most recent ones would seem to indicate that

```
    var shipsObj = $firebase(ref).$asObject(); // Is this necessary
    var ships = $firebase(ref);                // in the most modern version?

    var Ship = {
        all: shipsObj, // This works fine
        create: function (ship) {
            return shipsObj.$add(ship);  // This also works fine
        },
        find: function (shipId) {
            console.log($routeParams.shipId); // <--this ID appears as the correct numerical ID
```

Then, there is the next six lines, NONE of which work. They all produce an error indicating that they are undefined.

```
            console.log(shipsObj.$child(shipId));
            console.log(ships.$child(shipId));
            console.log(shipsObj.$getRecord(shipId));
            console.log(ships.$getRecord(shipId));
            console.log(ships.$keyAt(shipId));
            console.log(shipsObj.$keyAt(shipId));
        },
```

I won't bore you with repeating the next method multiple times as well, but `$remove` isn't working either.

```
        delete: function (shipId) {
            return ships.$remove(shipId);
        }
    };

    return Ship;
```

});

Comment: Personally, I don't believe that I need to be passing $routeParams into this service, but if I don't then instead of getting numerical ids, I get Firebase object names like `-JTdQa40CZ682o9p_fqy` and they seem to gum up the works as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your using v0.8 of AngularFire you'll want to use `$asObject()` or `$asArray()` to get at the actual data. Here's the official blog post that discusses the changes in v0.8: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-07-30-introducing-angularfire-08.html

So to access a ship by its id you could do:

```
var shipsObj = $firebase(ref).$asObject();
console.log(shipsObj[shipId]);
```

You may also want to take a look at the API docs for AngularFire: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/bindings/angular/api.html

A lot changed in v0.8 and it just came out (July 2014) so if you're basing your code on anything older than that then it probably won't work

Comment: Yes! Yes! Yes! Thank you! I have been at this for HOURS. And thanks for the blog post too. I will go through that.

Comment: You'll probably want to use $loaded to make sure the data is local before you try to console.log it. Note that this isn't necessary to use it in the view/dom, just for synchronous access in the controller.